# How can I tell whether I'm drilling into the chimney brick or a joint?

Tags: chimney

The chimney runs up the center of the house which is through my kitchen. I want to hang a pot rack on the plaster wall surrounding the chimney but have read on this site to be sure not to drill into the joint. Since a wall surrounds it there is no way to visualize the actual chimney or joints. Any ideas? Also, any specific bolt screw etc to use to hang a heavy pot rack?

Comment: Not sure about before (no stud finders for mortar) but during you can tell by the "sawdust" being excavated by the drill bit, specifically the color.

Comment: When putting a hook on a brick wall , I always drill the hole into the morter, it is much easier o drill than brick. If hanging something heavy ,I use a few holes with plastic plugs ( rawls ?).

Comment: Is the chimney actually in use? That will determine how critical a difference it is.

Comment: It is only used as a vent for the furnace and I think the water heater also. No fireplaces or anything like that.                    
   I should also mention that the house was built in 1890 if that makes any difference